# Python regex - why 'e42dsf425' is matched?

Tags: python, regex

pls check the regex below

```
import re

passwords = ['aaa5aa', 'adsfgg', 'e42dsf425']

regex = r'\w{3}\d{1}\w{2}'

for p in passwords:
    if re.findall(regex, p):
        print(p)
```

I dont uderstand why this regex match both: `aaa5aa` and `e42dsf425`. I expected to see only `aaa5aa` as we have `\d{1}` in the pattern.

Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Paweł

Comment: If your goal is to test these against your exact pattern try to change `re.findall` to `re.match` to test against a boolean return on a whole match. That should also forfeit the need for anchors `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

The short-hand `\w` includes `\d`. Use a character class instead:

```
[a-z]{3}\d[a-z]{2}
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

passwords = ['aaa5aa', 'adsfgg', 'e42dsf425']

regex = r'[a-z]{3}\d[a-z]{2}'

for p in passwords:
    if re.search(regex, p):
        print(p)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/9sd0VG).

---

`\w` is a short-hand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, whereas `\d` is `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `\w` also matches `\d`

You can match word characters without matching a digit:

```
[^\W\d]{3}\d[^\W\d]{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqITeY/1)

Note that [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list with all matches. The if statement here `if re.findall(regex, p):` checks if the list has a result.

If you want to match the whole string, you can use [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

```
import re
 
passwords = ['aaa5aa', 'adsfgg', 'e42dsf425']
 
regex = r'[^\W\d]{3}\d[^\W\d]{2}'
 
for p in passwords:
    if re.findall(regex, p):
        print(p)
```

Output

```
aaa5aa
```

If you want to match exactly 6 chars with a digit at the fourth position, you can use anchors:

```
^\w{3}\d\w{2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJyFVQ/1)